# php and true type collection in gd

Tags: php, gd, fonts, truetype

I try to use a true type collection "gulim.ttc" with 4 fonts in the GD libary.

Like this:

```
$font = "fonts/gulim.ttc";
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 0, 25, $white, $font, $string);
```

The Problem is, PHP/GD only uses the first font from the ttc-file but I need the third one called "Dotum".

Or, is there a way to extract or convert the ttc-file to a ttf-file?

Comment: I'm not even sure if GD properly supports .ttc

Comment: Bounty Note: I started a bounty on this as I'm also needing this same answer - **to extract or convert the ttc-file to a ttf-file**. For my situation, the preference is a .NET solution (or maybe just GDI P/Invoke). But any pointers (code, links, insight/discussion) that can allow me to do this programmatically would be appreciated – Otaku yesterday

Answer (score 4):

here are some links to a program that breaks TTC files into TTF: [link](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/breakttc.exe.11019.0.0.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever found anything, but I had the same problem and found the following life saving link... it has italic, centered, right justified, left justified, and underline.  The only thing that is missing is bold, which is pretty simple anyhow.

[php-imagestringright-center-italic](http://www.puremango.co.uk/2009/04/php-imagestringright-center-italic/)

**From the site:** 
"They even work with fonts you load via ImageLoadFont, which is pretty awesome!  You can even nest effects, to create for instance, right-aligned italic strings with a drop shadow!"

There’s an optional final parameter on each function, $ImageString, which contains a string representing the function to use to write the string. So for instance, if we want to write a right-aligned string in italics, we can use the following code:

```
ImageStringRight($image, 5, 25, 'Right + Italic', $col, 5, 'ImageStringItalic');
```

Answer (score 2):

There's some different methods here: https://superuser.com/questions/114603/how-to-install-os-x-ttc-font-on-windows-error-ttc-does-not-appear-to-be. And a pointer to source code in C. Here's another: http://solaris.sunfish.suginami.tokyo.jp/tips/playground/truetype/ttc2ttf/ttc2ttf.cpp

The only coding examples out there seem to be in Japanese...makes sense considering TTC files are pretty much for Asian languages. Anyway, I found this also: http://hdmr.org/d/read.php/1172771146 (probably need google translator for it).